# Windows 10, XAMPP Apache won't start after PHP update from 7.3 to 7.4

Tags: windows, apache

I tried to update `PHP7.3` to `PHP7.4` for my `XAMPP Apache` on `Windows 10`. Now `Apache` won't start...

I'm using a self-signed security certificate for development.

The error message I'm getting from Apache is:

```
10:30:53 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
10:30:53 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
10:30:54 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
10:30:54 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:30:54 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:30:54 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:30:54 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:30:54 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:30:54 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:30:54 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

These are the latest error log entries:

```
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:08.253500 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3120:tid 520] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:08.253500 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3120:tid 520] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:08.278953 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3120:tid 520] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

**I followed this tutorial:**
https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/how-to-upgrade-lower-version-to-latest-php-version-in-xampp-on-windows-f7be9a70bbb0

1. download Thread Safe PHP version from http://windows.php.net
2. unzip, rename folder to PHP
3. rename php folder in XAMPP (so mine is now php_7.3)
4. insert new php folder
5. inside this new php folder, I renamed php.ini.development to php.ini
6. then I replaced the PHP module lines in my `httpd-xamp.conf` as follows:

```
LoadFile "D:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "D:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "D:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

I'm not sure what to do and concerned that I will just mess it up even more... Help is very much appreciated! I really need Apache to work...

**EDIT:**

Here's today's complete error log:

```
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:07.558720 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 17248:tid 512] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:07.559723 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 17248:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:07.611001 2020] [core:warn] [pid 17248:tid 512] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:07.613027 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 17248:tid 512] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:07.613027 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 17248:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:07.648936 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 17248:tid 512] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:07.648936 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 17248:tid 512] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Aug 11 2019 12:20:04
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:07.648936 2020] [core:notice] [pid 17248:tid 512] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:07.655110 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 17248:tid 512] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3120
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:08.205628 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3120:tid 520] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:08.206625 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3120:tid 520] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:08.253500 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3120:tid 520] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:08.253500 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3120:tid 520] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 18 09:50:08.278953 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3120:tid 520] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

**EDIT 2:**

The result of running `httpd.exe` and `httpd.exe -t` command via the Windows command prompt:

```
"httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 537 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 17 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load D:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: The specified module could not be found."
```

Line 537 in `httpd.conf`is:

```
# XAMPP settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"
```

Line 17 in http-xampp.conf is:

```
LoadFile "D:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
```

Further research led me to this question about `php7ts.dll`: [php7ts.dll cannot load into server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416939/php7ts-dll-cannot-load-into-server)

So I ran the commands `httpd.exe -v` and `php.exe -v`.
The result is that they're both the 64-bit version, I think:

```
C:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd.exe -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64)
Apache Lounge VC15 Server built:   Aug 11 2019 12:20:04

C:\xampp\apache\bin>php.exe -v
PHP 7.4.7 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2020 13:36:15) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Those are warning messages not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm your confirm php7ts.dll file location and use same in apache httpd configuration file.

Comment: I updated my original post with today's error log. Before that, everything was running fine.

Comment: clear all file under `C:/xampp/apache/logs` directory and test.

Comment: I did. The error.log and access.log are now empty, after I was asked if I want to create the files because they're not existing. I also tried to access php_error_log. There it says "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Which command are you using to start httpd? Go to the bin folder execute httpd.exe and share result

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you mean. I used the command prompt to access xamp/apache/bin, then tried to run httpd.exe. Then I executed the httpd.exe -t  command. Both times the output is: `"httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 537 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 17 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xamp.conf: Cannot load D:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: The specified module could not be found."`

Comment: Please confirm php7ts.dll file location.

Comment: Ah, heh... This entire time I kept staring at it, thinking: it's right there, in that folder, I checked! But now I see, XAMPP is installed on C:, so it should be looking for `D:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll`, not D: ...there is no XAMP, PHP or any program installation on D:/

Comment: Could you use the proper path and let me know the result.

Comment: I changed the paths to `LoadFile “C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll”
LoadModule php7_module “C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll”`but it's still not starting. Running `httpd.exe` now returns: `httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 537 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 19 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Invalid LoadFile path \xe2\x80\x9cC:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll\xe2\x80\x9d`

Comment: This looks like double quote issue. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767925/apache-doesnt-load-module-from-php

Comment: Thank you so much! Apache is now running! :) ...when I enter localhost in the browser, it still gives me a "localhost refused to connect." `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` But it is progress. :')

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the settings of apache are correct:

1. Open command prompt and navigate to your apache installation bin folder: `cd C:/xampp/apache/bin`
2. Then run the following command to see if the syntax is OK:
   `httpd.exe -t`